# dplyr rename_ produces an error when renaming columns with spaces

Tags: r, dplyr

`rename_` works as expected for non-pathological column names

```
%>% rename_(foo = 'testcol')
```

But what if I'd like to rename a column which has a space?

```
%>% rename_(foo = 'test col')
```

I get an error that says:

```
Error in parse(text = x) (from #12) : <text>:1:6: unexpected symbol
```

I could use `make.names` but is there no way to rename a column without that extra step?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not just using the standard `rename` or for that matter simply doing `names(df)[2] <- "foo"`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try with `backquotes`

```
%>% rename(foo = `test col`)
```

Using a reproducible example

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    rename(foo = `test col`) %>%
    head(3)
#        Col1 foo
#1 -0.5458808   C
#2  0.5365853   N
#3  0.4196231   R
```

Or using `rename_` (though I am not sure if this is correct syntax as usually `.dots` are needed.)  Using similar syntax from OP's post

```
df %>%
      rename_(foo = quote(`test col`)) %>%
       head(3)
#        Col1 foo
#1 -0.5458808   C
#2  0.5365853   N
#3  0.4196231   R
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 df <- data.frame(Col1= rnorm(10), 'test col' = sample(LETTERS, 10),
        check.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: This is `rename` not `rename_` though.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, `rename_` needs `.dots` inside.  Without a reproducible example from OP, it is hard to understand what his objective is

Comment: @thelatemail I updated with a possible working way with `rename_`.  But, I am not sure if this can be used in general.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the underlying reason for this behavior. To fix the problem, @akrun's answer is probably more suitable.

Most `dplyr` functions use `lazyeval` internally. And the character method for `lazyeval::as.lazy` cannot handle spaces. A possible fix would be to add the `around character strings with spaces inside`as.lazy.character`.

```
require(lazyeval)
as.lazy.character <- function (x, env = baseenv()){
  if (grepl(pattern = "[:space:]", x) & !grepl(pattern = "`", x))
    x <- paste0("`", x, "`")
  lazy_(parse(text = x)[[1]], env)
}
```

Or better yet (from @hadley's suggestion)

```
as.lazy.character <- function (x, env = baseenv()){
  if (grepl(pattern = "[:space:]", x) & !grepl(pattern = "`", x))
    return(as.lazy(as.name(x), env))
  lazy_(parse(text = x)[[1]], env)
}
```

That fixes the `rename_`, as well as any other functions using `as.lazy` internally:

```
dplyr::select_vars_(names(df), "test col")
dplyr::rename_(df, foo="test col")
dplyr::mutate_(df, "foo" = "test col" )
```